# Shuffle a numpy array

Tags: python, random, numpy, shuffle

I have a 2-d numpy array that I would like to shuffle. Is the best way to reshape it to 1-d, shuffle and reshape again to 2-d or is it possible to shuffle without reshaping?

just using the random.shuffle doesn't yield expected results and numpy.random.shuffle shuffles only rows:

```
import random
import numpy as np
a=np.arange(9).reshape((3,3))
random.shuffle(a)
print a

[[0 1 2]
 [3 4 5]
 [3 4 5]]

a=np.arange(9).reshape((3,3))
np.random.shuffle(a)
print a

[[6 7 8]
 [3 4 5]
 [0 1 2]]
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can tell `np.random.shuffle` to act on the flattened version:

```
>>> a = np.arange(9).reshape((3,3))
>>> a
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])
>>> np.random.shuffle(a.flat)
>>> a
array([[3, 5, 8],
       [7, 6, 2],
       [1, 4, 0]])
```

Comment: how to shuffle a matrix so that the correspondences between rows and columns are retained? For example, row *and* column 1 would be shuffled to row and column 3 in the shuffled matrix

Answer (score 8):

You could shuffle `a.flat`:

```
>>> np.random.shuffle(a.flat)
>>> a
array([[6, 1, 2],
       [3, 5, 0],
       [7, 8, 4]])
```

Answer (score 7):

I think this is **very importan**t to note.
You can use `random.shuffle(a)` 
if `a` is 1-D numpy array.
If it is N-D (where N > 2) than

> random.shuffle(a)

will spoil your data and return some random thing.
As you can see here:

```
import random
import numpy as np
a=np.arange(9).reshape((3,3))
random.shuffle(a)
print a

[[0 1 2]
 [3 4 5]
 [3 4 5]]
```

This is a known [bug](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/1655) (or feature?) of numpy.

So, **use only** `numpy.random.shuffle(a)` for **numpy arrays**.