# Strange behaviour when using random.shuffle on numpy.array

Tags: python, numpy

```
import numpy as np
from random import shuffle

a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
print(a)
for i in range(1000):
    shuffle(a)
print(a)
```

Output:

```
[[1 2 3]
 [4 5 6]]
[[1 2 3]
 [1 2 3]]
```

Get two `[1, 2, 3]`, `[4, 5, 6]` is missing.

```
import numpy as np
from random import shuffle

a = np.arange(10).reshape(5,2)
print(a)
for i in range(1000):
    shuffle(a)
print(a)
```

Output:

```
[[0 1]
 [2 3]
 [4 5]
 [6 7]
 [8 9]]
[[0 1]
 [0 1]
 [0 1]
 [0 1]
 [0 1]]
```

All items in the array become first item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic issue occurs because `random.shuffle` uses the following (code can be found [here](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/c6880edaf6f3/Lib/random.py#l288)) -

```
x[i], x[j] = x[j], x[i]
```

If you do this kind of assignment for Numpy array (like in your case) , you get the issue -

```
In [41]: ll
Out[41]:
array([[7, 8],
       [5, 6],
       [1, 2],
       [3, 4]])

In [42]: ll[0] , ll[1] = ll[1] , ll[0]

In [43]: ll
Out[43]:
array([[5, 6],
       [5, 6],
       [1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
```

The following example may be able to show why the issue occurs -

```
In [63]: ll = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8]])

In [64]: ll[0]
Out[64]: array([1, 2])

In [65]: x = ll[0]

In [66]: x
Out[66]: array([1, 2])

In [67]: y = ll[1]

In [68]: y
Out[68]: array([3, 4])

In [69]: ll[1] = x

In [70]: y
Out[70]: array([1, 2])
```

As you can see when you set `ll[1]` to a new value, `y` variable reflected the change as well, this is most probably because numpy might be mutating `ll[1]` inplace (please note, I am not talking about `ll` , `ll[1]` the inner `ndarray` of `ll` ) instead of assigning the object referenced by `x` to `ll[1]` (like it happens in case of lists) .

---

As a solution you can use [`np.random.shuffle()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.shuffle.html) instead of `random.shuffle()` -

```
In [71]: ll = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8]])

In [72]: ll
Out[72]:
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [5, 6],
       [7, 8]])

In [73]: from numpy.random import shuffle

In [74]: shuffle(ll)

In [75]: ll
Out[75]:
array([[7, 8],
       [3, 4],
       [1, 2],
       [5, 6]])
```

Please do note, `np.random.shuffle()` only shuffles elements along the first index of a multi-dimensional array. (Though if `random.shuffle()` worked , it would have worked like that as well) .

Answer (score 3):

numpy.random.shuffle(a) should do what you want. Playing around with random.shuffle on the terminal, it doesn't seem to handle matrices very well.

[Shuffle a numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22426609/shuffle-a-numpy-array)