# Shuffle 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, random, shuffle

I was trying to shuffle 2D array, and I encountered some stange behavior, that can be resumed with the following code:

```
import random
import numpy

a = numpy.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
random.shuffle(a)
print 'With rand\n', a

a = numpy.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
numpy.random.shuffle(a)
print 'With numpy\n', a
```

Output

```
With rand
[[1 2 3]
 [1 2 3]
 [1 2 3]]
With numpy
[[4 5 6]
 [7 8 9]
 [1 2 3]]
```

As you can see, with `random` library (my first try), it seems to overwrite elements (or something else, I really don't understand what happen here), consequently the shuffling is not performed. 
However with `numpy` library, it works perfectly.

Can anyone explain me why? I.e. where does this difference come from? And if possible, what does the `random.shuffle` function does with 2D array?
Thanks,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shuffle a numpy array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22426609/shuffle-a-numpy-array)

Comment: The question is not really a duplicate but the answer is indeed [there](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35183004/3545273)

Comment: @SergeBallesta: Yes indeed, the answer is in one of the answer, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a check for `random` source code..

https://svn.python.org/projects/stackless/trunk/Lib/random.py

```
def shuffle(self, x, random=None, int=int):
    """x, random=random.random -> shuffle list x in place; return None.

    Optional arg random is a 0-argument function returning a random
    float in [0.0, 1.0); by default, the standard random.random.
    """

    if random is None:
        random = self.random
    for i in reversed(xrange(1, len(x))):
        # pick an element in x[:i+1] with which to exchange x[i]
        j = int(random() * (i+1))
        x[i], x[j] = x[j], x[i]
```

the last line as you see: make the `shuffle` fails because numpy somehow perform the last line **in parts** 
, but python lists perform it altogether ..

Answer (score 0):

`random.shuffle` is designed to work with a `list` and not an `array`. Basically, you should use `random.shuffle` whenever you have a `list` and `np.random.shuffle` when you are working with an `array`.

```
a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
random.shuffle(a)

b = numpy.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
numpy.random.shuffle(b)
```